# How to copy ssh key into Python Docker image?

Tags: python, docker, ssh

Where is the user's home directory, specifically `~/.ssh`, in a python3.* [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)?

I need to add a specific SSH key to an image so it can access a private git repo at run-time.

Articles [like this](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/) explain how to do this, but it still depends on the underlying image, and I don't know what the "python" image is based on, since it doesn't conform to any standard Linux distro.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can put the key anywhere; `~/.ssh` is just the default location. You can adjust whatever command uses the key to look in a specific location.

Comment: That said, the standard Python image doesn't have any regular users, only `root` and various services accounts. `/root/.ssh` doesn't exist by default, but you can create it.

Comment: If you are using some other image, you'll have to give us more details about how the image was created.

Comment: You really don't want to copy ssh keys into an image, since it's very easy to read them back out.  But the answers to the linked questions go through a lot of options (bind mounts, multi-stage builds, buildkit extension options, ...).

Comment: In the Docker Hub image pages like the one you link to, the version tags are links to their respective Dockerfiles.  "Buster" images are Debian-based, "Alpine" ones are Alpine-based.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, that's what I thought but I was looking for confirmation.

Comment: @DavidMaze That's a fair point, but not a problem for my use case. The image is only used during a build to run some unittests in a standardized environment, and is immediately thrown away afterwards.

Comment: @Cerin Rather than adding them to the image, mount a directory containing the keys when you create the container.